# Redis cluster won't failover after port "blocking"

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have a problem with redis cluster failover with some specific scenatio.

There is a cluster with 6 nodes ( 3 master + 3 slaves connected with cluster bus, all of this setting up in VM virtual box on my laptop, OS used on VMs - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ):

```
ef4492597e4a2f8892c54bd6155ea50f621b129f 10.0.2.27:6379@16379 master - 0 1690375867508 26
connected 0-5460
d5ce0438ca2bd59da0d81b8daac7d0eed55c51a1 10.0.2.29:6379@16379 master - 0 1690375866503 3
connected 10923-16383
ea34a7f981010c5753c9a54ccd2245ef1892d466 10.0.2.28:6379@16379 master - 0 1690375866000 2
connected 5461-10922




5f75d37fad97aee9cb1d07856b6781682ad4dee3 10.0.2.30:6379@16379 myself,slave
ef4492597e4a2f8892c54bd6155ea50f621b129f 0 1690375868000 26 connected
9cc9b5f679e61390c3c4bd964dc293291c4a103f 10.0.2.32:6379@16379 slave
d5ce0438ca2bd59da0d81b8daac7d0eed55c51a1 0 1690375870000 3 connected
1344811c0cc34641da31416fcea51f82cfbf84b2 10.0.2.31:6379@16379 slave
ea34a7f981010c5753c9a54ccd2245ef1892d466 0 1690375869000 2 connected
```

On 10.0.2.27 I apply filters via iptables in order to create a situation where the application (redis-server in this case ) can connect to the server, but cannot exchange traffic at the same time:

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags PSH PSH --dport 6379 -j DROP (this for limit main redis port )
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags PSH PSH--dport 16379 -j DROP ( this for limit redis cluster bus port )

After that I expect that the cluster detect that 10.0.2.27 is unavailable now, and promote it's replica ( 10.0.2.30 ) to a master. But it don't happens.

In log on replica I see only this:

```
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:36:53.907 # Connection with master lost.
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:36:53.907 * Caching the disconnected master state.
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:36:53.907 * Reconnecting to MASTER 10.0.2.27:6379
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:36:53.907 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:36:53.907 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:37:54.025 # Timeout connecting to the MASTER...
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:37:54.025 * Reconnecting to MASTER 10.0.2.27:6379 after failure
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:37:54.025 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:37:54.025 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:38:55.297 # Timeout connecting to the MASTER...
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:38:55.297 * Reconnecting to MASTER 10.0.2.27:6379 after failure
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:38:55.297 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:38:55.297 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:39:56.570 # Timeout connecting to the MASTER...
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:39:56.570 * Reconnecting to MASTER 10.0.2.27:6379 after failure
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:39:56.570 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:39:56.570 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:40:57.841 # Timeout connecting to the MASTER...
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:40:57.841 * Reconnecting to MASTER 10.0.2.27:6379 after failure
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:40:57.842 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:40:57.842 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:41:58.119 # Timeout connecting to the MASTER...
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:41:58.119 * Reconnecting to MASTER 10.0.2.27:6379 after failure
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:41:58.119 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:41:58.119 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:42:59.383 # Timeout connecting to the MASTER...
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:42:59.383 * Reconnecting to MASTER 10.0.2.27:6379 after failure

784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:42:59.383 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:42:59.383 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:44:00.645 # Timeout connecting to the MASTER...
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:44:00.645 * Reconnecting to MASTER 10.0.2.27:6379 after failure
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:44:00.645 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:44:00.645 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:45:01.897 # Timeout connecting to the MASTER...
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:45:01.897 * Reconnecting to MASTER 10.0.2.27:6379 after failure
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:45:01.897 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
784:S 26 Jul 2023 14:45:01.898 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
```

Replica just trying reconnect to the master but it can't, becuase of ip tables filters.

And there is a two variations of this scenario:

1. After a certain time (approximately 5-6 minutes), 10.0.2.27 was recognized as a failure and the cluster tried to promote its replica 10.0.2.30 to the master, but could not do this due to the cluster-replica-validity-factor setting. More than 310 seconds have passed since the last reply,
   as a result, the replica was not recognized as valid, the failover did not occur, and the cluster went to the fail state.

Log from 10.0.2.30:

```
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:34:42.092 # Connection with master lost.
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:34:42.092 * Caching the disconnected master state.
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:34:42.092 * Reconnecting to MASTER 10.0.2.27:6379
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:34:42.092 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:34:42.092 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:37:43.892 # Timeout connecting to the MASTER...
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:37:43.892 * Reconnecting to MASTER 10.0.2.27:6379 after failure
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:37:43.892 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:37:43.892 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:38:05.297 * FAIL message received from 1344811c0cc34641da31416fcea51f82cfbf84b2 about ef4492597e4a2f8892c54bd6155ea50f621b129f
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:38:05.297 # Cluster state changed: fail
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:38:25.342 # Currently unable to failover: Disconnected from master for longer than allowed. Please check the 'cluster-replica-validity-factor' configuration option.
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:40:44.570 # Timeout connecting to the MASTER...
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:40:44.570 * Reconnecting to MASTER 10.0.2.27:6379 after failure
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:40:44.570 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:40:44.571 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:43:25.096 # Currently unable to failover: Disconnected from master for longer than allowed. Please check the 'cluster-replica-validity-factor' configuration option.
```

2. 

After a certain time (approximately 5-6 minutes), 10.0.2.27 was recognized as a failure and the cluster tried to promote its replica 10.0.2.30 to the master, and the replica successfully became the master. (as expected )

Log from 10.0.2.30:

```
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:12:54.375 # Connection with master lost.
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:12:54.375 * Caching the disconnected master state.
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:12:54.375 * Reconnecting to MASTER 10.0.2.27:6379
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:12:54.375 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:12:54.376 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:13:30.792 * FAIL message received from ea34a7f981010c5753c9a54ccd2245ef1892d466 about ef4492597e4a2f8892c54bd6155ea50f621b129f
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:13:30.792 # Cluster state changed: fail
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:13:30.803 # Start of election delayed for 956 milliseconds (rank #0, offset 2814).
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:13:31.808 # Starting a failover election for epoch 21.
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:13:31.812 # Failover election won: I'm the new master.
803:S 26 Jul 2023 08:13:31.812 # configEpoch set to 21 after successful failover
803:M 26 Jul 2023 08:13:31.812 * Discarding previously cached master state.
803:M 26 Jul 2023 08:13:31.812 # Setting secondary replication ID to 9a4ea420199a83c454c20782a3dc1e502c436131, valid up to offset: 2815. New replication ID is b7e8122cbbca2b0d75d379de2a6866e0b53c91af
803:M 26 Jul 2023 08:13:31.812 # Cluster state changed: ok
803:M 26 Jul 2023 08:13:34.916 * Replica 10.0.2.27:6379 asks for synchronization
803:M 26 Jul 2023 08:13:34.916 * Partial resynchronization request from 10.0.2.27:6379 accepted. Sending 0 bytes of backlog starting from offset 2815.
```

But in most of my tries 10.0.2.27 don't recognized a failure by cluster and nothing happens.

In this two additional scenarios, setting repl-timeout set as 180 ( 60 now ), and cluster-replica-validity-factor is set to 10 (w\o changing ), and tcp-keepalive was 300 ( 100 now ).

After that I expect that the cluster detect that 10.0.2.27 is unavailable now, and promote it's replica ( 10.0.2.30 ) to a master

I'm trying to check the config and change tcp-keepalive parameter to 100, changing repl-timeout from 180 to 60, another setting looks fine.

I collect a tcpdump from replica, but i didn't find anything useful. Just want to understand why it don't want do failover. I attach my config and tcpdump from my last try.

Answer (score 0):

I only applied iptables filters to incoming traffic. However, since the master node was able to send pings to the rest of the cluster, it was not considered down. Applying a similar filter on outbound traffic immediately triggered a failover

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).